# Assets(bootstrap) does not run properly after assets precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I use gem less-rails-bootstrap.

When I execute rake assets:precompile, the application runs just fine in production mode 
(rails s -e production). But when i run in the development mode, my bootstrap modal does not work properly.

I fixed this by running rake assets:clean and set config.serve_static_assets = false (default)

can anyone tell me what's going on?

Comment: What is different between production & development? Your app might use precompiled assets in production or something. Have you got any more info? Code or something?

Comment: I didn't touch the code. just compiled assets to production then running on development. Suddenly my bootstrap modal not working properly until assets that i compiled before is cleaned

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue once, though not necessarily with the less-rails-bootstrap gem. Have you tried refreshing your browser cache? (Shift + F5 in Chrome/Firefox I think).